# Android Jsoup получить значение ссылки

Tags: android, jsoup

Есть исходный код сайта

```
  <div class="online">
       <div class="online__item online__item_now">
            <span class="online__item_now__label">Сейчас онлайн:</span>
            <a class="online__link online__woman" href="/search_women">
               <span class="icon"></span>4 324</a>
            <a class="online__link online__man" href="/search_men">
               <span class="icon"></span>7 291</a>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Как получить значение **/search_women** ? При каждой перезагрузке страницы разные значения этой ссылки, то есть разное количество человек, интересует как получить именно число/строку значение ссылки, то что в данном коде **4 324**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чем проблема то? Взять и в лоб распарсить как-то так:

```
Document doc;
try {
      doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("my_file.html"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
Elements my_a = doc.getElementsByClass("online__link online__woman");          
for (Element temp : my_a)
    String my_number = temp.text(); 
    //Дальше можно преобразовать в число или дальше обработать как вздумается
```